# Accessing a compressed file in an apk from native code (read a zip from inside a zip)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, zip, zlib

**The background:**

In trying to make the codebase (C/C++) for my app more portable, I would like to minimize my use of android's native AAssetManager and switch to libzip for loading assets from the APK. I had a look at libzip; merged it into the project and - lo and behold - I can read my files directly from the APK using libzip.

Now, I would like to obfuscate my assets (or at least make access to them non-trivial), so I thought I'd package them into an encrypted zip archive and include that archive in the APK (basically, a zip in a zip).

**My question:**

*What would be the easiest/most effective way to access the files in the archive directly from within the APK using native code?*

I was hoping for a similar approach as with libzip, where I can simply specify a filename and then get a buffer with uncompressed data.

I have tried opening the compressed archive directly from within the APK using libzip, but I'm coming up empty... it appears libzip will only open a zip file using a directory and not from a buffer in memory (which is as far as I got).

I suppose zlib would be an obvious choice, but I admit I have no clue how to go about it.

I also thought about copying the archive out of the APK, but I would like to waste as little space as possible (lots of assets == big archive). Delivery of the assets as a separate download is also something I'd like to avoid.

Helpful suggestions or pointers are welcome.

Comment: Just a note from a former hacker: such obfuscation is cracked pretty easily. Moreover, putting an encrypted zip into a ZIP is a big red arrow saying "look for interesting suff here".

Comment: Yeah, well... I have no illusions about that. I realise it may be easy to hack, but anything is better than leaving the assets in plain sight. The more more important issue here for me is portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you've already got past getting to the asset stream in your APK, so I'll jump right to this: As you say, zlib is an obvious choice. There are tons and tons of examples online to process in-memory streams. For example, [In Memory Decompression: GZIP](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/02/decompressing-files-into-memory/). With zlib you also have the benefit that it's already available via the NDK (e.g. you don't need to build and link in your own).

Comment: +1 for the relevant links, looks like the pkzip/minizip portion will be useful. If there are no further contributions in the next few days I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: If there is additional information you need, I'd be happy to update the answer.

Comment: In the end I decided to copy the archive out of the apk to an external location and access the contents from there. As the link you provided technically answers the question, I'm more than happy to accept your contribution as the answer.